# What causes execution plans to be removed from plan cache quickly?

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I wonder what causes an execution plan to be removed from the SQL Server 2012 (SP3) plan cache very quickly (< 1 minute).

When I run this script in my code, the plan exists at the beginning but has aged out in under 1 minute with no other meaningful activity taking place.  This is on a dev machine with 16G of RAM with over 8G free at time of execution.  SQL Server instance is limited to 2G max memory.

```
create table Temp923835 (id int);
go
insert into Temp923835 select message_id from sys.messages;
go
select count(*) from Temp923835 a inner join Temp923835 b on (a.id=b.id) where a.id > 3 
go

SELECT 'First Pass' as Phase, query_plan, text
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text ( cp.plan_handle ) st 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan ( cp.plan_handle ) qp 
where text like 'select count(*) from Temp923835%';

waitfor delay '00:01:00';

SELECT 'Second Pass' as Phase, query_plan, text
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text ( cp.plan_handle ) st 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan ( cp.plan_handle ) qp 
where text like 'select count(*) from Temp923835%';

drop table Temp923835;
```

I would expect the cache to linger for a little while longer.

Comment: Had to check real quick to remind myself...sounds like a memory issue anyways. SQL Server keeps the plan for a while by default, but since it is stored in memory, your plans can be replaced if the cache for it is limited in space. You should find out what your memory consumption is via the system tables. For example, each query is allocated a certain amount of memory before execution, so if you have some abominations occurring,  you wont /may not see the I/O high,but your memory is sapped.

Comment: You appear to be correct.  Updating maximum memory to 4 GB on my local machine allows the 1 minute test to pass consistently.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @clifton_h noted in a comment above, it is memory related.  I changed instance maximum memory to 4GB from 2GB and now the test script passes consistently.